# I need a regex for Decimal Number

Tags: expression, decimal

I need a regular expression that validates a decimal number, but doesn't require any symbol befor number . ie.

.2 (fine)

.12 (fine)

12     (fine)

12.0  (fine)

12.12  (fine)

But

12.123 (not allow)

-12.12(not allow)

+12.12 (not allow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[0 to 9 as many times as it is possible or none] dot [0 to 9 1 or times]

```
/^([0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

Edit: added starting and ending limiters.

Answer (score 1):

The original answer requires numbers <del>before the decimal and numbers after it.</del> after the decimal.

Hooray for edits.

`([0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?`

Comment: You saw the old version :)

Comment: Indeed. Your current version still requires a decimal and numbers after it, which doesn't fit with his 3rd "valid" sample: 12

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this solution there are multiple online REGEX debuggers. One of my favorite is:
http://www.debuggex.com/

It will allow you to put in language, REGEX, and sample data.